# Navegador não abre o HTML com CSS

Tags: css

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }    
        #box1{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url(i1.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            display: table;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        #box2{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url(i2.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            display: table;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        #box3{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url(i3.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            display: table;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        h1{
            font-family: arial black;
            font-size: 50px;
            color:white;
            margin: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box1">
            <h1>DAFT CREATION</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="box2">
            <h1>DAFT CREATION</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="box3">
            <h1>DAFT CREATION</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: E o que acontece no navegador?

Comment: Como você está tentando acessar? O que está aparecendo? Tente acessar o console (a maioria das vezes F12 o abre) e veja se está retornando algum erro.

Comment: simplismente nada, a guia abre mas fica tela branca, ele sabe que o conteúdo está ali, pois da pra abaixar a tela, mas não aparece nada

Comment: No console ele fala que deu erro ao carregar a imagem

Comment: Na verdade a pergunta mesmo é por que ele não consegue carregar as imagens, estou tentanto fazer um efeito de PARALLAX

Comment: aos downvoters sugiro comentar o porque fizeram isso, dar um downvote e não ajudar o usuário novo a ver o porque sua pergunta foi negativada não ajuda em nada

Answer (score 4):

É porque o css do seu h1 contém a linha: `color:white`.

Por isso o texto está branco.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você definiu a cor do seu H1 como branco no CSS. Não tem nada de errado quando executo a pagina, os textos são exibidos porem se o seu fundo também for branco não vai conseguir ver mesmo.